# display utf-8 char from json in php

Tags: php, json, utf-8, yql

I am using a public api, YQL, in particular, it returns a json, and in this josn there is a field that is Chinese character.
By calling this api url directly, I am able to view the json in browser, and it does show the chinese character in the browser in json form (meaning it is beding decoded correctly and readable i suppose)

now, in php, i call this same api url via curl (it should return the same json as i were calling it directly in browser)

```
$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$yql_json = curl_exec($session);
```

i print the returned json in the follow format via php

```
print_r($yql_json . "\n\n");
print_r(utf8_decode($yql_json) . "\n\n");
```

and it returns the following respectively,

```
{"query":{"count":2,"created":"2012-08-19T07:24:51Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"h1":{"class":"entry-title","content":"åº·ç†™ä¾†äº† 2012-06-21 å¥³å­ç†è²¡ä¾¿æ˜¯å¾·?!"}}}}


{"query":{"count":2,"created":"2012-08-19T07:24:51Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"h1":{"class":"entry-title","content":"???? 2012-06-21 ????????!"}}}}
```

as you can see, the chinese char does not show up (after "content")

my goal is to eventually take the content field (the chinese chars) and insert to database, but clearly example above doesn't seem to be in correct chinese value to insert or in utf-8 encoding

basically what i am also asking is that how can i have the chinese char displayed in the above print statements, becuase if i can do that, it means i have the correct utf-8 encoding to insert to database.

please help

i guess my question is:
1. which of the print statement has the correct information for me to insert to database?

edit:

suggested by one of the answers that i should insert the utf8_decode version (the one with ?? and !! above)

i did just that with the following code

```
$sql = "UPDATE myTable SET title='" . utf8_decode($yql_json_php["query"]["results"["h1"["content"]) . "' WHERE id='4'";
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

i refresh my page, but it still showing up as ?? and !!

i pasted chinese character directly into the table via sequel pro application, i am able to display the data on my webpage

so it has to do with the UPDATE sql i have...the db doesn't seem to know it is utf8

Comment: Seem your file is not saving as UTF8 with BOM, try to use notepad++ convert you file from ascii to utf8

Comment: Read: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

OR

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: thanks but i am NOT trying to display the utf-8 char, i am not sure which print statements i posted above has the correct utf-8 char information for me to insert to database.

Comment: If using this displays correct output, you can insert your content field in database. 
json_decode your json response and simply inset the content field in your database and fetch that field an check whether its output is comming correct or not.

Comment: my page can display chinese chars.  if i just copy a chinese text and pasted it to a table field directly (via sequel pro application), my page displays the chinese fine...but i have two issues: 1. am i inserting correct chinese value from the json?  i am able to insert, but when my page reads that field i just saved from db, it doesn't show up as chinese char

Comment: can you post the json response.
'mysql_set_charset('utf8');' use it after database connection and check.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. basically you are getting the chinese characters. But while you are printing it , or storing it in database they might show up as "?????" . and again when you retrieve it and display it in browser, you can see the chinese character. To get rid of "????" in database, you will have to define the characterEncoding in database url and set character_set_result and few others to utf8. Meanwhile, if you debug your application and see the value of content on watch , you would actually see the chinese characters. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i guess my question is:
1. which of the print statement has the correct information for me to insert to database?

Comment: 2nd one. send the utf8 decoded content to be inserted in database.

Comment: are you setting useUnicode and characterEncoding in mysql connection string : something like - "jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/databasename?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" if not. try it out. I am pretty sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. $yql_json = iconv(in_charset, 'utf-8', $yql_json);
2. header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
3. web page view coding -> utf-8